Which version of Quart to use?
I have a very simple Flask website running on my Synology NAS. I discovered that I probably need asyncio capabilities.
I found out that these do not work with Flask. Via Google I learned that Quart is derived from Flask and that it has asyncio capabilities.  So, I installed Quart and tried to run a site similar to the one under Flask.  Without success: server error.
So, I switched to a very simple example from the Quart docs Quickstart section. Again:internal server error.
I think that it may have to do with compatibility of Quart with my Python install.
I have Python 3.9 and cannot change that because the Synology Web Portal leaves no other choice. That runs fine with Flask 3.0.3.
Now I have Quart 0.19.6. Should that be OK with Python 3.9?  Are there earlier versions of Quart that can work with Python 3.9?

I found out that the uWSGI system that is used in Synology Web Portal for Python applications is not suitable for async applications such as Quart. This would need a ASGI server, which is not available on my Synology NAS.
